# Extract substring from a variables between two patterns in bash with special characters

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I am trying to Extract substring from variables between two patterns in bash that as special characters inside the variable.

***The variable:***

MQ_URI=ssl://b-7dda5da6-59a5-4150-8e2f-16534985665-1.mq.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:61617?jms.prefetchPolicy.queuePrefetch=0

What I've tried so far:

```
echo "$MQ_URI" | sed -E 's/.*ssl:// (.*) :61617.*/\1/'
```

Got me this in response:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 12: unknown option to `s'
```

Also tried with grep:

```
echo $MQ_URI | grep -o -P '(?<=ssl://).*(?=:61617jms.prefetchPolicy.queuePrefetch=0)
```

The output I need is everything between: `"ssl://"` and `":61617?jms.prefetchPolicy.queuePrefetch=0"`

which is : `"b-7dda5da6-59a5-4150-8e2f-16534985665-1.mq.us-east-1.amazonaws.com"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `bash`

```
$ mq_uri=${mq_uri##*/}
$ mq_uri=${mq_uri//:*}
$ echo "$mq_uri"
b-7dda5da6-59a5-4150-8e2f-16534985665-1.mq.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
```

`sed`

```
$ sed -E 's~[^-]*/([^?]*):.*~\1~' <<< "$mq_uri" 
b-7dda5da6-59a5-4150-8e2f-16534985665-1.mq.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
```

`grep`

```
$ grep -Po '[^-]*/\K[^:]*' <<< "$mq_uri" 
b-7dda5da6-59a5-4150-8e2f-16534985665-1.mq.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
```

`awk`

```
$ awk -F'[/:]' '{print $4}' <<< "$mq_uri" 
b-7dda5da6-59a5-4150-8e2f-16534985665-1.mq.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is what you expect

```
echo "$MQ_URI" | sed -E 's@.*ssl://(.*):61617.*@\1@'
b-7dda5da6-59a5-4150-8e2f-16534985665-1.mq.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
```

replace the delimiters by `@` or anything not found in the string.

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples and attempts please try following codes.

```bash
##Shell variable named `mq_uri` being created here.
##to be used in following all solutions.
mq_uri="ssl://b-7dda5da6-59a5-4150-8e2f-16534985665-1.mq.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:61617?jms.prefetchPolicy.queuePrefetch=0"
```

---

***1st solution:*** Using `awk`'s `match function along with` split` function here.

```bash
awk 'match($0,/^ssl:.*:61617\?/){split(substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH),arr,"[/:]");print arr[4]}' <<<"$mq_uri"
```

***2nd solution:*** Using GNU `grep` along with its `-oP` options and its `\K` option to get required output.

```bash
grep -oP '^ssl:\/\/\K[^:]*(?=:61617\?)' <<<"$mq_uri"
```

***3rd solution:*** Using `match` function of `awk` along with using `gsub` to Globally substitute values to get required output.

```bash
awk 'match($0,/^ssl:.*:61617\?/){val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH);gsub(/^ssl:\/\/|:.*\?/,"",val);print val}' <<<"$mq_uri"
```

***4th solution:*** Using `awk`'s `match` function along with its array creation capability in GNU `awk`.

```bash
awk 'match($0,/^ssl:\/\/(.*):61617\?/,arr){print arr[1]}' <<<"$mq_uri"
```

***5th solution:*** With `perl`'s One-liner solution please try following code.

```bash
perl -pe 's/ssl:\/\/(.*):61617\?.*/\1/' <<<"$mq_uri"
```